# Hibernate generic field

Tags: java, hibernate, generics, jpa, spring-data

I'm trying to create the mapping classes in Hibernate of the following database table:

```
CREATE TABLE values (
    id SMALLINT,
    name NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    type NVARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    text NVARCHAR(MAX) NULL,
    numeric NUMERIC NULL,
    boolean BIT NULL,
    date DATETIME NULL,
    CONSTRAINT c1 CHECK(type IN ('TEXT','NUMERIC','BOOLEAN','DATE'))
);
```

Currently I have the following implementation, but I wouldn't want to redefine each property in each subclass of values beacuse it does not use the generic implementation of the parent:

**Value**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "values")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "type")
public abstract class Value<T extends Serializable> {
    @Id
    private int id;
    private String name;
    @Transient
    private T value;

    public T getValue() {
        return value;
    }
    public void setValue(T value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

**Value types**

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("TEXT")
public class TextValue extends Value<String> {
    private String text;

    @Override
    public String getValue() {
        return text;
    }
}
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("NUMERIC")
public class NumericValue extends Value<Double> {
    private Double numeric;

    @Override
    public Double getValue() {
        return numeric;
    }
}
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("BOOLEAN")
public class BooleanValue extends Value<Boolean> {
    private Boolean boolean;

    @Override
    public Boolean getValue() {
        return boolean;
    }
}
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("DATE")
public class DateValue extends Value<LocalDateTime> {
    private LocalDateTime date;

    @Override
    public LocalDateTime getValue() {
        return date;
    }
}
```

I have tried to use `@AttributeOverride` in order to change the column name in each of the subclasses, but it had no effect.

If there is another alternative of achieve the key-value structure of the table above and can be mapped using generics in Java will be valuable too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using a different mapping, instead of @Transient value:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "values")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "type")
public abstract class Value<T extends Serializable> 
{
    @Id
    protected int id;

    protected String name;


    public abstract T getValue();

    public abstract void setValue(T value);
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("TEXT")
public class TextValue extends Value<String> 
{
    @Column(name = "text")
    private String value;

    @Override
    public String getValue() 
    {
        return value;
    }

    @Override
    public void setValue(String value) 
    {
        this.value = value;
    }
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("NUMERIC")
public class NumericValue extends Value<Double> 
{
    @Column(name = "numeric")
    private Double value;

    @Override
    public Double getValue() 
    {
        return value;
    }

    @Override
    public void setValue(Double value) 
    {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

and so on

---

Well, benefits are very limited, since I think you may want something like this:

```
@Entity
public class Something
{
    ...

    @OneToMany(cascade = ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "SOMETHING_ID")
    private Set<Value<?>> values = new LinkedHashSet<>();

    ...
}
```

In this case the only benefit is that the internal value is converted by ORM to the right class, so it is not your responsibility.

Nevertheless you have to (and you can't avoid it, with any other model) pollute your business logic / presentation controller with cumbersome `instanceof`.

Comment: Thanks for your response. But in this case, what would be the benefits of using generics? I was trying to avoid this approach because I found no utility in the flexibility a generic class would bring, if I have to redefine the same value in each subclass.